# Cassandra pagination done right?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I'm looking to sanity check my approach to paginating a Cassandra table. My use case is the following: I need a table that gives me the last X visitors to a website on a given day, to power an analytics dashboard. I log the visits with a session_id, and I have the following table schema:

```
session_id text,
yyyymmdd test,
bucket int,
timeuuid timeuuid,
primary key((yyyymmdd, bucket), timeuuid)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timeuuid DESC)
```

The bucket is there to avoid hotspots on one node. On to pagination: 
The query will look something like this:

```
SELECT session_id FROM recent_visitors WHERE yyyymmdd = ? AND bucket IN (?) LIMIT 1000;
```

Now, this query will most likely affect every node, since the bucket number is larger than the number of nodes. Will this query be too expensive/ is there a better way? Also, I know that for each partition, the data is sorted by clustering column, but will cassandra sort the result from all the partitions? In other words, the data will be returned sorted within each (yyyymmdd, bucket) group, but across groups will I have to sort the result for final display? Then, if I get the oldest timeuuid from the result, I am planning on paginating with the following query:

```
SELECT session_id FROM recent_visitors WHERE yyyymmdd = ? AND bucket IN (?) LIMIT 1000 WHERE timeuuid < previous_oldest_timeuuid;
```

Is that a sane approach? Thank you in advance for you time.

Answer (score 1):

For some basics of modeling a time series in Cassandra see the following article:

http://planetcassandra.org/blog/getting-started-with-time-series-data-modeling/

Your data model looks sane, but I would change your read query.  You are going to be better off sending off a bunch of queries for the different buckets asynchronously rather than querying them as a batch like that.

Your result set from the batch is going to be ordered per bucket, so you will have to combine the different buckets together either way, and it is better to only hit one server with each query, rather than have one query which will hit multiple servers.